# Contact form 7 with dynamic text extension - layout issue

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 with the dynamic text extension.

What I am trying to achieve is to add contact form 7 to each of my portfolio page. But I would like the subject to be pre-filled with the post title.

With the dynamic text extension, I am able to get the field prefilled.
However the layout of the field box is messed up.

For example (dashes are empty space):

|Field 1 ---------- |

|Field 2 -------|

|Field 3 ---------- |

|Field 4 ---------- |

Field 2's width, height, font, and color are not consistent with the other fields.

Does anyone know how to make it consistent with other fields?

Comment: it's not easy to say without viewing the code, can you share it?

Comment: There's really no code to this... all I did was install the plugin and fill out the fields.

Comment: I know, what i meant is, we need to see the code of the layout / link to the website to see what the issue is about, if it's about the form layout so i think you meant to the CSS design you need to change, it seems like you are talking about the width of the inputs and the text area because they are coming with different width setting -> set input and textarea to the same width, if you are not using "box-sizing: border-box" yet so I think you should because then you can set all the input types and the textarea to width 100% no matter the padding value, and wrap the form with limited width.